# Domain name automatically getting prepended to a href link

Tags: whmcs

I have installed WHMCS and I am using this template which i have changed a bit here and there. However, I wanted to add a modal window for which I need to add an a href="" link. The problem is that i want the href to be just #modal1 where as it automatically prepends www.youdomain.com/whmcs/ to this link. I don't know from where this is happening. I have looked in to the htaccess of whmcs and there is nothing in it. Is there anyway I can use an a href without that getting prepended in to whmcs templates? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you said "this template", but didn't provide a template name or link. When you view source, do you see the www.yourdomain.com/whmcs/ or empty link. May be you editing the wrong file? it would be great if your provide a link to the page.

Comment: http://www.shade6.com/client/cart.php?gid=3 on this link you'll find a link to compare all products. I just got it done with jquery using preventDefault method. But is there a way in which you can override any settings that may by default cause all hyperlinks to append the path?

Comment: Glad you got it working. Regarding the href, it is not adding any thing. If you view source and check href for Compare Products link, you will see href="", which means it is blank, if you click the link (with no preventDefault) it will redirect you to the directory containing the current file which is shade6.com/client/. You can edit manually and add href="#modal1".

Comment: Hey..it shows href="" because thats what I have put in there.. but it is not blank in 'real' sense. if you point at the link and see down left.. it shows shade6.com/client/. as you rightly said, without the preventDefault it will take me to shade6.com/client/. However, I have tried putting #modal1 there. What happens is, it redirects you to www.shade6.com/client/#modal1. which means the path is automatically getting prepended. I have tired everything and the only way I could succeed was using javascript.

Comment: And I must also mention that the modal window has a close button which also for no reason goes to www.shade6.com/client/. For that as well I had to use the same javascript method. Which means there is something in the template that causes the path to prepend itself to everylink.

Answer (score 1):

You're using bootstrap3 modal without specifying some important data attributes. I checked your code and applied the missing data attributes for modal to be automatically initialized by bootstrap and it was working as expected.

For the modal div, add `data-dismiss="modal"` to the close button a element. this will close the modal with adding any custom code.

For the "Compare products" link, add the products link in the href, add data-toggle, and add data-target, as given below:

```
<a href="http://www.shade6.com/hosting/sslcertificate.html" class="sslcert" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">Click to compare all products</a>
```

Also, remove (or comment) the custom code you added to make the link and close button works.

For more information about how to use the modal, check [bootsrtap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Comment: Hey, thanks. This works. However, I was actually not using the bootstrap modal. I was using a different modal. But using this data-toggle technique works.

Comment: @PankajLohia Accept answer please.

Comment: How do I do that? I tried clicking on the up arrow but it says it will reflect the changes after I cross 15 points.

Comment: @PankajLohia work hard to earn them then :) thank you

Comment: I'm sorry for not being able to get you points. But it will reflect on your account once I get 15.